# iOS10 widget "Show more" "Show less" bug

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, ios10-today-widget

I have implemented the new widget for iOS 10 and I have used the following code to set the height for it:

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.Compact {
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 350.0)
    }
    else if activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.Expanded {
        self.preferredContentSize = desiredSize
    }

}
```

And it´s working fine, but my issue is with the **"Show more"** and **"Show less"** buttons. They don't always respond and I do very often have to click more than once to trigger them. I´m I missing something? Do I have to add more than the above code to handle the height?

Comment: The values you are setting are not valid and might be causing a problem. You should use the `maxSize` variable when the display mode is `.Compact` and make sure the height you choose is not larger. Also, a width of 0 might be causing bugs, use the width of your view.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue , the problem was that i had updated the `preferredContentSize` even if the widget was in the compact mode.

Try to check every place where you update the `preferredContentSize` and update the size only if the if `widgetActiveDisplayMode` is `NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded`

Comment: I'm updating the size of my widget by using a constraint for the height of a stack view, rather than relying on the preferredContentSize. I'm still getting the error message despite I don't touch that property at all in my implementation. I also get the "Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from … (null)" error before the "No active animation block!" error.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3:**

```
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayMode.compact) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.preferredContentSize = yourFixSize
        }, completion: nil)

    }
    else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.preferredContentSize = yourMaxSize
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

had same problem , and I found that when we click the "show more" “show less” button , there is no animation. So you can try to add a block like this :

```
- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize {

    if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                         animations:^{
                             self.preferredContentSize = yourFixSize;                          }];
    }
    else {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                             animations:^{
                                 self.preferredContentSize = yourMaxSize;
}];
        }
}
```

I fix this bug in this way .

Hope useful